# How do I efficiently generate data with random variation in a time series based on existing data points

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a handful of data points in a csv as follows:

```
          date      value
0     8/1/2019   0.243902
1    8/17/2019   0.322581
2     9/1/2019   0.476190
3    10/6/2019   0.322581
4   10/29/2019   0.476190
5   11/10/2019   0.526316
6   11/21/2019   1.818182
7    12/8/2019   2.500000
8   12/22/2019   3.076923
9     1/5/2020   3.333333
10   1/12/2020   3.333333
11   1/19/2020   0.000000
12    2/2/2020   0.000000
```

I want to generate a value for every hour between the first date and the last date (assuming that each one starts at 00:00 on that date) such that the generated values create a fairly smooth curve between each existing data point. I would also like to add a small amount of random variation to the generated values if possible so that the curves are not perfectly smooth. I ultimately want to output this new dataset to a csv with the same two columns containing the original rows along with the generated values and their associated datetimes (each in its own row).

Is there way to easily generate these points and output the result to a csv? I have thus far tried using pandas to store the data but I can't figure out a way to ensure that the generated data takes the existing data points into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `scipy.interpolate`:

```
# this is the new timestamps
new_date = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max() + pd.to_timedelta('23h'),
                         freq='H')

from scipy import interpolate

tck = interpolate.splrep(df['date'].astype('int64'), df['value'], s=0)
new_values = interpolate.splev(new_date.astype('int64'), tck)

# visualize
plt.plot(df.date, df.value, label='raw')
plt.plot(new_date, new_values, label='intepolated')
plt.legend();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to add a bit more variation or "noise" to the data after generating it?

Comment: @Nizag generate a random noise with `np.random.normal` and add to the signal?